# Counting the number of times a value is repeated in a row using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through a row in a pandas data frame, checking if there are any similar values and if there are similar values, I want to count how many times the value is repeated disregarding the first time and record it in a column.

Input:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [['K1', 'K2', 'K1', 'R3', 'R1', 'K3'], 
     ['K2', 'K4', 'K4', 'R2', 'R2' ,'R2']], 
    columns=list('ASDFEI')
)

    A   S   D   F   E   I
0  K1  K2  K1  R3  R1  K3
1  K2  K4  K4  R2  R2  R2
```

The link contains an image showing what I am trying to do. In the first row, only K1 is repeated once so the count is 1. In the second row, K4 is repeated once and R2 is repeated twice so the count would be 3.

[image]

Comment: For the second row, count is 3 because that's the maximum number of repeats?

Comment: Welcome to Python and SO. Try to recreate the dataframe here on SO. Images is a big no no.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it is because k4 is extra once, and R2 twice so, 2+1 =3.

Comment: Like I said, I am new to Python, so creating a data frame here as an example is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: @AtiqulIslam There are many things you can do to share it. One is to simply print it `print(df.head(2))` and copy paste. Another is to print it in dict format: `print(df.head(2).to_dict())` and paste it here.

Comment: Thank you i will try that next time'

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
# Insert column count with count of duplicated (keep=First is default)
df.insert(0,'Count', df.T.apply(pd.Series.duplicated).sum())

print(df)
```

Returns

```
   Count   A   S   D   F   E   I
0      1  K1  K2  K1  R3  R1  K3
1      3  K2  K4  K4  R2  R2  R2
```

---

**Update:** You can create a boolean mask with  pd.Series.isin() and `~` to filter away undesired results.

- Use axis=1 to iterate over rows
- Use sum(axis=1) to calculate sum of rows
- Use astype(int) to convert to float

---

```
# Create new Series with count of duplicated (keep=First is default)
newcol = (df.apply(lambda x: x[~x.isin(['TK',np.NaN])]
           .duplicated(), axis=1).sum(axis=1).astype(int))

# Insert column
df.insert(0,'Count', newcol)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   Count   A    S    D   F   E   I
0      1  K1   TK   K1  R3  TK  K3
1      2  K2  NaN  NaN  R2  R2  R2
```

Comment: You can speed this up a bit: `df.T.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, keep='first').sum()`

Comment: Yes. In general apply is slow, but apply + lambda is worse.

Comment: I tried this, but its counting the empty cells as well. I was wandering what can I add to avoid counting certain values like cells containing NaN or cells containing TK

Comment: @AtiqulIslam ok I will add an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can `stack` your frame and call `groupby` + `value_counts`

```
df['Count'] = (df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts() - 1).sum(level=0)
df

    A   S   D   F   E   I  Count
0  K1  K2  K1  R3  R1  K3      1
1  K2  K4  K4  R2  R2  R2      3
```

Or, using `insert` (as shown by @Anton vBR),

```
df.insert(
    0, 'Count', (df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts() - 1).sum(level=0)
)
df

   Count   A   S   D   F   E   I
0      1  K1  K2  K1  R3  R1  K3
1      3  K2  K4  K4  R2  R2  R2
```

Comment: I tried this, it gave me a empty column called count.